# while creating sample app of Gallery. I am facing following error. Please do helpful

Tags: flutter

Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then
move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

In build.gradle>dependencies>  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'

Answer (score 0):

Goto file in android studion select project structure and update your gradle